# add a query parameter to /objetc api call in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was asked to add a query parameter to a '/object' API call
(and implement it - I think the parameter is suppose to be a function)

I was googling all day and could not find out what this means

thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you could explain it, or perhaps put code sample? It would get your question answered sooner and better

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#parameters

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what this means:

```
/object?someParam=someValue&otherParam=otherValue
```

Query parameters can't be functions - they are a part of URL.

You can build such URL manually or using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is sent from client-side to the backend it's the part after the `?` mark in a URL.. For example : [add a query parameter to /objetc api call in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476873/add-a-query-parameter-to-objetc-api-call-in-react?aParam=someValue)

To get this in code and use it, the params will be an object..
so :
`{ aParam: "someValue" }`